# Firefox redirects https to http for some urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, ssl

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application, and I'm getting very strange behavior in firefox 15. I'm browsing to url: https://www.mydomain.com/test, but it gets redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/test (so from https to http). In IE 9 this is not happening. I did some logging on the server side, and Request.IsSecureConnection is false in the Controller action. Does anybody have any suggestion for how to debug this type of problem?

Note that I don't necessarily need to force https, it can be either http or https, but when the user is authenticated, it should remain in https to safely transport the session ID cookie.

EDIT: I strongly suspect Firefox is caching whatever I visit first. On one machine I started (I think) with http, and there it won't let me do https on that url. On another machine (VM), I start with https, works ok, and it won't let me do http on the same url. So it looks like Firefox has some strange caching behavior.

Comment: Did you look at the network traffic in FireBug?  There is either a redirect being issued or Firefox doesn't like your https site for some reason.  Might be a bad cert or insecure content being loaded that is causing Firefox to switch to http.

Comment: Gets stranger by the minute. In one tab with Firebug, it will do https, in the other tab also with Firebug it refuses to do https, and it will just do http requests (even if I enter the https url).

Comment: Did you look at the network traffic?  What do the requests and responses look like?

Comment: Yes, sometimes Firefox decides to do http, and sometimes it does https, regardless of what I enter in the url.

Comment: Ok, having a look with Fiddler. First time I open the url with https, goes ok. I switch to http, goes ok. I switch back to https, now it does http. Also I notice in the "Caching" column in fiddler, it is set to private. No idea what that means, but I'm digging further.

Comment: Also tried with Google Chrome, works fine. Firefox seems to be the only browser that has this strange behavior.

Comment: But, the issue only happens on the asp.net mvc pages, not on the static pages or php pages on my site. Maybe some issue with the mvc ssl negotiation?

Comment: Correction: just tested again on static .html and .php, the same issue also happens there in firefox. It's kind of random so it's hard getting a consistent verdict. So I'm getting more convinced this is a firefox bug.

Comment: Checked the bugzilla bug database, and it seems to be a bug indeed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781617. Half a day down the drain!